# Small number of weights in the SVM separator function

Tags: machine-learning, svm

The separator function in SVM is:

$f(\mathbf{x})=\sum\limits_{\mathbf{x_i} \in Support}\alpha_i\times K(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x_i})-b$

Depending on the kernel, this may correspond to adding any number of attributes to the original problem. However, there are only as many weights $\alpha_i$ as there are support vectors. How does this *not* limit the model's expressive power by forcing dependencies on the relative importance of the attributes?